# Custom Sudoku Puzzle Size

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows, sudoku

I have the following code for creating a 4 x 4 Sudoku puzzle. But the problem with this code is that the Sudoku board that it generates is too big. I'm looking to generate a much smaller, perhaps one-half or three-fourth the size of what this code currently gives me, Sudoku board that I can populate. I heard that one can do this using the Tikz package, but after playing around with it all day, I got no where.

One other thing that I would like to do after being able to generate smaller 4 x 4 Sudoku boards is to be able to situate 2 or more such Sudoku boards side by side. So any help is greatly appreciated! As a side note, I am using ShareLatex.com to write a report.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}{%
\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{30pt}\centering\Huge\sffamily}p{19pt}

\newcommand\TPLine{\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}}

\newcounter{shrow}
\newenvironment{shidoku}
  {\setcounter{shrow}{0}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}}}
  {\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\newcommand\Srow[4]{%
  \ifnum\value{shrow}=0 \TPLine\fi\stepcounter{shrow}%
  #1 & #2 & #3 & #4\tabularnewline
  \ifnum\value{shrow}=2 \TPLine\else\ifnum\value{shrow}=4 \TPLine\else\hline\fi\fi}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}

\begin{shidoku}
\Srow{1}{2}{3}{4}
\Srow{3}{4}{1}{2}
\Srow{4}{3}{2}{1}
\Srow{2}{1}{4}{3}
\end{shidoku}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's just me, but your code does not compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`logicpuzzle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/logicpuzzle) package for this task. It provides some well known puzzles environments, but you can create your own environments like a 4x4 sudoku:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}

\newenvironment{shidoku}[1][]{%
\begin{logicpuzzle}[rows=4,columns=4,#1]
\begin{puzzleforeground}
\framepuzzle
\framearea{black}{(1,1)--(3,1)--(3,3)--(1,3)--cycle}
\framearea{black}{(3,3)--(3,5)--(5,5)--(5,3)--cycle}
\end{puzzleforeground}
}{\end{logicpuzzle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{shidoku}
\setrow{1}{1,2,3,4}
\setrow{2}{3,4,1,2}
\setrow{3}{4,3,2,1}
\setrow{4}{2,1,4,3}
\end{shidoku}
%
\begin{shidoku}[scale=.5, fontsize=scriptsize]
\setrow{1}{1,2,3,4}
\setrow{2}{3,4,1,2}
\setrow{3}{4,3,2,1}
\setrow{4}{2,1,4,3}
\end{shidoku}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]