# How to draw 15-puzzle in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I need to draw 15-puzzle in LaTeX, that is, a diagram of a 4x4 grid with numbers inside. Could you please recommend me a package for doing this and some example code?

[image: 15-puzzle]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please look into https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282967/custom-sudoku-puzzle-size

Answer (score 15):

With [`logicpuzzle`](https://ctan.org/pkg/logicpuzzle)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}

\newenvironment{fifteen}[1][]{%
\begin{logicpuzzle}[rows=4,columns=4,#1]
\begin{puzzleforeground}
\framepuzzle
\end{puzzleforeground}
}{\end{logicpuzzle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{fifteen}
\setrow{4}{13,10,11,6}
\setrow{3}{5,7,4,8}
\setrow{2}{1,12,14,9}
\setrow{1}{3,15,2,}
\end{fifteen}
%
\begin{fifteen}
\setrow{4}{13,10,11,6}
\setrow{3}{1,5,7,4}
\setrow{2}{3,12,14,8}
\setrow{1}{,15,2,9}
\end{fifteen}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Congrats to 100k!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

This puts a list in the minimal quadratic grid that is large enough to fit it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Puzzle}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydim}{dim({#2})}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myrows}{sqrt(\mydim)+0.99}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mymax}{max(#2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysize}{width("\mymax")+8}%
\draw (0,0) grid[step=\mysize pt] (\myrows*\mysize pt,-\myrows*\mysize pt);
\foreach \Z [count=\Cn starting from 0] in {#2}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Y}{\Cn/\myrows}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\X}{\Cn-\Y*\myrows}%
\unless\ifnum\Z<0
\node[minimum size=\mysize pt,anchor=north west] at (\X*\mysize pt,-\Y*\mysize pt) {\Z};
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\Puzzle{13,10,11,6,5,7,4,8,1,12,14,9,3,15,2}

\Puzzle{13,10,11,6,5,7,4,8,1,12,14,9,3,15,2,13,10,11,6,5,7,4,8,1,12,14,9,3,15,2,3,4}

\Puzzle{13,10,-1,11,6,-1,5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However your solution does not allow to place the empty pebble anywhere else than at the last position.

Comment: @Brikowski Now it is possible. Negative entries will be ignored, i.e. lead to empty cells.

Answer (score 7):

A simplified variant on my answer here: [Vertically centered material in fixed height rows in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509978/vertically-centered-material-in-fixed-height-rows-in-tabular-environment/510000#510000)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\cellwd
\newcount\cellht
\makeatletter
{\catcode`|=\active \gdef|{\acell}}
\newcommand\acell[1]{\noindent%
  \framebox(\cellwd,\cellht){\centering#1}\kern\@wholewidth\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\cellrowskip{\\[\dimexpr-1pt+\@wholewidth\relax]}
\newenvironment{celltable}[2][\@wholewidth]
  {\cellwd=#2\relax
  \cellht=#2\relax
  \linethickness{#1}%
  \vspace{#1}%
  \par\catcode`\| \active 
}{\par}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
What precedes.

\begin{celltable}{30}% CELL SIZE IN PT
|{13}|{10}|{11}|6\cellrowskip
|5|7|4|8\cellrowskip
|1|{12}|{14}|9\cellrowskip
|3|{15}|2|~
\end{celltable}

What follows.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if the cell size is of no consequence, a simple `tabular` will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
What precedes.

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
13 & 10 & 11 & 6\\
\hline
5 & 7 & 4 & 8\\
\hline
1 & 12 & 14 & 9\\
\hline
3 & 15 & 2 &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

What follows.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can tweak the intercolumn spaces with @{\,} or similar for a more pleasant look.